# React Native download and open file - file is blank on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs, rn-fetch-blob

So, I am using `react-native-fs` to download files from a url and then open to view/share/print them with `react-native-file-viewer`. This works fine for iOS but on Android there is an issue. I assume the file is downloading correctly since when passing `FileViewer` the path of the file it "opens" the file. Although, all that is displayed is a blank screen.

Here's my implementation:

```
  const fileName = 'AnImageFile.png';
  const dir = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
  const filePath = dir + '/' + fileName;

  const options = {
    fromUrl: url,
    toFile: filePath,
  };

  RNFS.downloadFile(options)
  .promise.then(() => FileViewer.open(filePath, {showOpenWithDialog: true, showAppsSuggestions: true}))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('File should have opened');
    // Hits here, opens blank on Android
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('There was an error opening the file');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

[Screenshot of image being opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV9Q6.png)

I have also tried using `rn-fetch-blob` instead of `react-native-fs` for downloading the file. But when passing `FileViewer` the path from that, it cannot locate the file. I think I am closer with the solution above using `react-native-fs` since the file downloads and can be located, but I might be completely wrong about this. Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, posting in case this finds useful to someone else... If you are on android trying to download then open a file and it opens blank you most likely don't have permissions. This is regardless of which file viewing and downloading tools you use. https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/483#issuecomment-761763626

Solution I used:

```
RNFS.downloadFile(options)
  .promise.then(()=> PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  ]))
  .then((result) => {
    const isGranted = result[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] === 'granted' 
    && result[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] === 'granted';

    isGranted ? FileViewer.open(filePath, {showOpenWithDialog: true, showAppsSuggestions: true}) : console.log('Declined')})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('File should have opened');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const downloadFile = async (path, url) => {
 const filePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + path + '/' + 
  'video.mp4';

 RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: url,
      toFile: filePath,
      background: false,
      cacheable: false,
      connectionTimeout: 60 * 1000,
      readTimeout: 120 * 1000,
 }).promise.then((r) => {
 console.log('promise result: ', r);

    FileViewer.open(filePath, {showOpenWithDialog: true, 
      showAppsSuggestions: true}) : console.log('Declined')});
   });
 };
```